# React - Can someone make this work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I found this beautiful layout done by a gentleman named Sean, over on Codepen, which he used React to create this horizontal accordion.

The code is below but [here](https://codepen.io/nevernotsean/pen/YpmWoM) is the Codepen if you need to fork it.

So, the issue I'm having is; how would one be able to use different 'projects' in each 'category'. Right now all the 'categories' are using the same 'projects'. I believe it's something simple I'm not undestanding but I just can't find it.

```js
class ProjectList extends React.Component {
createProjectListItem(project) {
    let byline = project.acf.project_byline
    let client = project.acf.project_client
    return (
        <li key={'project-' + project.id}>
            <a to={'/projects/' + project.slug}>
              <h3 className="projectlist--client">{client}</h3>
              <h4 className="projectlist--byline">{byline}</h4>
            </a>
        </li>
    );
}
render() {
    return (
        <div className="project-list">
            <ul className="menu vertical">
              { this.props.projects.map( this.createProjectListItem ) }
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
    }
}

class ProjectCategory extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.setActive = this.setActive.bind(this)

        this.state = {
          projects: []
        }
    }
    componentWillMount() {
      // this.getProjects(); // Codepen switched to HTTPS, so I have to load JSON manually instead of the json-generator
      this.setState({
        projects: [{"acf":{"project_byline":"ut ullamco sunt","project_credits":[{"credit_role":"ut","credit_name":"Leann"},{"credit_role":"aliquip","credit_name":"Hernandez"},{"credit_role":"consequat","credit_name":"Ashlee"}],"project_description":"Enim est qui Lorem officia adipisicing irure minim. Eu enim fugiat cupidatat elit anim pariatur irure quis aute velit enim. Adipisicing consequat sunt eiusmod reprehenderit nisi fugiat esse ut. Consequat ea ad deserunt mollit quis labore Lorem do qui officia labore. Incididunt reprehenderit anim sunt velit sunt est sit anim.","project_client":"pariatur","project_thumbnail":"https://unsplash.it/1000/1000","project_category":"aute"},"tags":["incididunt"],"categories":[2],"excerpt":{"rendered":"Eiusmod reprehenderit incididunt aute do commodo sint laboris exercitation Lorem excepteur sit cillum aute irure."},"content":{"rendered":"Enim id ex excepteur incididunt in deserunt mollit eiusmod adipisicing officia quis aliquip. Qui aute et consequat consectetur aute consectetur laborum. Non non sint reprehenderit velit proident aliqua elit eiusmod laboris veniam elit ea. Incididunt excepteur et esse minim amet in magna ea enim."},"title":{"rendered":"non"},"link":"https://seanma.de","guid":"7d115e77-9566-4389-b544-deffaf76d058","slug":"proident","id":"58653533ca121cbaf664b199"},{"acf":{"project_byline":"consectetur aute aliquip","project_credits":[{"credit_role":"dolor","credit_name":"Hampton"},{"credit_role":"mollit","credit_name":"Kate"},{"credit_role":"consectetur","credit_name":"Riddle"}],"project_description":"Reprehenderit in mollit fugiat cupidatat consectetur minim Lorem eiusmod commodo laboris dolor minim tempor eiusmod. Et aute et exercitation dolore fugiat pariatur in ipsum anim dolor qui laborum laborum. Elit qui ad ea exercitation laboris sunt ut et est sunt duis. Esse duis ad ipsum aliqua nulla enim minim minim. Ullamco do tempor ex magna et ipsum sint et voluptate cupidatat anim labore esse.","project_client":"et","project_thumbnail":"https://unsplash.it/1000/1001","project_category":"nisi"},"tags":["et"],"categories":[8],"excerpt":{"rendered":"Ipsum excepteur laboris nostrud sit proident."},"content":{"rendered":"Anim non Lorem id fugiat. Do cillum qui veniam qui ad mollit pariatur Lorem. Lorem veniam nulla commodo aliqua. Fugiat laboris cillum excepteur tempor aliqua sit exercitation sit labore nostrud et."},"title":{"rendered":"in"},"link":"http://seanma.de","guid":"444da15a-5160-48bb-bf6f-7d820d1f62e8","slug":"dolor","id":"58653533702dae7921a80c46"},{"acf":{"project_byline":"eiusmod ullamco commodo","project_credits":[{"credit_role":"nulla","credit_name":"Dickson"},{"credit_role":"esse","credit_name":"Trevino"},{"credit_role":"aliquip","credit_name":"Joni"}],"project_description":"Ullamco minim occaecat officia anim laborum laboris velit cupidatat esse aliqua irure exercitation. Occaecat elit labore est exercitation aute qui voluptate adipisicing consectetur officia. Adipisicing tempor tempor culpa enim cupidatat.","project_client":"magna","project_thumbnail":"https://unsplash.it/1000/1002","project_category":"consectetur"},"tags":["incididunt"],"categories":[3],"excerpt":{"rendered":"Tempor quis cupidatat elit quis aute velit amet pariatur cupidatat ullamco voluptate."},"content":{"rendered":"Elit commodo aliqua do occaecat consectetur sint ex. Eiusmod proident eiusmod ullamco occaecat cillum voluptate duis. Tempor enim ullamco duis sint est. Minim voluptate sint nisi enim ut pariatur officia cillum excepteur sint aliquip. Amet in proident dolor amet incididunt laborum sint commodo cillum officia consectetur proident aliqua. Incididunt nostrud nulla mollit adipisicing adipisicing nulla exercitation."},"title":{"rendered":"tempor"},"link":"http://seanma.de","guid":"75909710-4410-4b59-bec8-f5cbb342471a","slug":"ullamco","id":"58653533e961f59631955144"},{"acf":{"project_byline":"culpa tempor commodo","project_credits":[{"credit_role":"eiusmod","credit_name":"Pennington"},{"credit_role":"fugiat","credit_name":"Jocelyn"},{"credit_role":"enim","credit_name":"Byrd"}],"project_description":"Cupidatat incididunt laborum cillum ea dolore quis. Exercitation Lorem eu ad ex. Laboris ipsum excepteur sunt eu irure ipsum. Consequat cupidatat sunt Lorem proident nostrud velit voluptate nulla quis cillum fugiat. Mollit fugiat nulla enim irure commodo officia nulla minim incididunt labore. Labore cillum irure Lorem ut laborum ad laborum.","project_client":"sint","project_thumbnail":"https://unsplash.it/1000/1003","project_category":"do"},"tags":["adipisicing"],"categories":[7],"excerpt":{"rendered":"Nostrud laborum aliquip enim aute aute tempor."},"content":{"rendered":"Consectetur fugiat commodo aliquip culpa occaecat anim cupidatat adipisicing cupidatat voluptate reprehenderit incididunt. Irure consequat enim deserunt incididunt dolor nisi id do cupidatat in Lorem. Laborum amet id minim enim. Nulla sint enim commodo ut qui duis reprehenderit Lorem nulla. Ad sint aliquip aute Lorem ut reprehenderit duis dolore occaecat non. Elit deserunt amet laborum non labore est deserunt eiusmod."},"title":{"rendered":"nulla"},"link":"http://seanma.de","guid":"9581e2ce-8146-4cf5-8d0b-9107ab850828","slug":"non","id":"58653533c66184064ccedc40"},{"acf":{"project_byline":"ex deserunt est","project_credits":[{"credit_role":"non","credit_name":"Hutchinson"},{"credit_role":"quis","credit_name":"Donaldson"},{"credit_role":"aliqua","credit_name":"Marcie"}],"project_description":"Eu ullamco anim adipisicing duis adipisicing sint sit incididunt pariatur sit. Non veniam deserunt nulla aute. Eiusmod minim ut Lorem consequat. Ut ad ad qui do aute. Duis ipsum do consequat exercitation nisi anim id laboris fugiat dolore ex ut consectetur excepteur. Esse deserunt nostrud esse consectetur pariatur mollit. Enim proident enim non occaecat eu sint nostrud.","project_client":"occaecat","project_thumbnail":"https://unsplash.it/1000/1004","project_category":"sit"},"tags":["aliqua"],"categories":[3],"excerpt":{"rendered":"Esse commodo amet excepteur ex ad."},"content":{"rendered":"Commodo ad et veniam sunt non pariatur elit ex anim esse consequat veniam. Ad magna nulla ea anim est in nostrud magna magna proident voluptate officia. Irure nisi do adipisicing nostrud mollit est non duis quis nisi amet veniam Lorem proident."},"title":{"rendered":"mollit"},"link":"http://seanma.de","guid":"472ababf-2340-4301-b63d-9bec9640a19e","slug":"incididunt","id":"586535332e3781792a099619"}]
      })
    }
    getProjects() {
      let _this = this
      let catid = this.props.cat.id
      let url = 'http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/EyrhxmRVz'
      fetch(url).then( response => response.json() )
      .then( json => { _this.setState({ projects: json }) })
    }
    getBackground(i){
      let _this = this

      // let bgArray = this.state.projects.map(function(project){
      //   return project.acf.project_thumbnail
      // });

      let bg = this.props.cat.thumbnail

      return bg
    }
    setActive() {
        this.props.handleClick(this.props.Index)
    }
    getWidth(isActive) {
        let w = 'calc(20vw - 20px)'
        if (isActive) { w = '500px' }
        return w
    }
    render() {
      // console.log(this.state.projects) 
        let name = this.props.cat.name
        let thumbnail = this.getBackground()

        let { active, focused, shiftLeft, isLast } = this.props

        let styles = {
          container: {
            transform: (function() {
                return (active)
                    ? 'scale(1.1) translate3d(0, 0, 0)'
                    : 'scale(1) translate3d(0, 0, 0)'
            })()
          }, item: {
              transform: (function() {
                  let direction = (shiftLeft) ? '-': ''
                  let transform = 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)'
                  if (focused) {
                    if (!active) {
                      transform = 'translate3d('+ direction +'100%, 0, 0)'
                    }
                  }
                  return transform
              })()
          }, background: {
              background: 'url(' + thumbnail + ') no-repeat center center',
              backgroundSize: 'cover',
              height: '500px',
              width: (this.getWidth(active))
          }
        }
        let classes = classNames({category: true, isActive: active, isLast, shiftLeft})
        return (
            <li className={classes} style={styles.item}>
                <div className="category--content">
                    <h2>{name}</h2>
                    <ProjectList projects={this.state.projects}/>
                </div>
                <div className="category--image-container" onClick={this.setActive} style={styles.container}>
                    <div className="category--image" style={styles.background}></div>
                </div>
                <div className="category--name">
                  <h6>{name}</h6>
                </div>
                <div className="category--closeButton">
                  <a href="#">Back</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        )
    }
}

class Collection extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this._handleClick = this._handleClick.bind(this)
        this.categoryNode = this.categoryNode.bind(this)
        this._focusOff = this._focusOff.bind(this)

        this.state = {
          open: false,
          activeIndex: null,
          categories: []
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      // this._getCategories(); // Codepen switched to HTTPS, so I have to load JSON manually instead of the json-generator
      this.setState({
        categories: [{"thumbnail":"https://unsplash.it/1200/1200","link":"http://seanma.de","taxonomy":"category","count":6,"name":"consequat","slug":"commodo","id":"586537da62981d5fb8c21617"},{"thumbnail":"https://unsplash.it/1200/1201","link":"http://seanma.de","taxonomy":"category","count":8,"name":"non","slug":"laborum","id":"586537da60c040bc1e3060a1"},{"thumbnail":"https://unsplash.it/1200/1202","link":"http://seanma.de","taxonomy":"category","count":3,"name":"non","slug":"commodo","id":"586537daffc67c66ec4dc356"},{"thumbnail":"https://unsplash.it/1200/1203","link":"http://seanma.de","taxonomy":"category","count":6,"name":"velit","slug":"voluptate","id":"586537dae1be34396786ce5f"},{"thumbnail":"https://unsplash.it/1200/1204","link":"http://seanma.de","taxonomy":"category","count":2,"name":"non","slug":"voluptate","id":"586537dab274a22da2f3edae"}]
      })
    }
    _getCategories() {
      let _this = this
      let url = 'http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/E1NpHQAEf';
      fetch(url).then( response => response.json() )
      .then( json => { _this.setState({ categories: json }) })
    }
    _handleClick(i){
      this.setState({
        activeIndex: i,
        open: true
      })
    }
    _focusOff(e){
      e.preventDefault()
      if (e.target.className !== 'category--image') {
        this.setState({
          activeIndex: null,
          open: false
        })
      }
    }
    categoryNode(cat, i){
        let isLast = ( i === this.state.categories.length - 1 || i === this.state.categories.length - 2)
        let shiftLeft = ( i < this.state.activeIndex )

        return (
          <ProjectCategory
            cat={cat}
            key={'cat-' + i}
            handleClick={this._handleClick}
            active={i === this.state.activeIndex}
            focusOff={this._focusOff}
            focused={this.state.open}
            shiftLeft={shiftLeft}
            Index={i}
            isLast={isLast}
          />
        )
    }
    render() {
      let catNodes = this.state.categories.map(this.categoryNode)
      let classes = classNames({
        focused: this.state.open
      })
      return (
        <div className={'categories--menu-container ' + classes} onClick={this._focusOff} style={{height: window.innerHeight}}>
          <ul className="categories menu">
            {catNodes}
          </ul>
        </div>
      )
    }
}

class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="App">
        <Collection/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"))
```

```css
html, body {
  background-color: #222;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  color: white;
}

a:hover, a:hover > * {
  color: grey;
}

.categories--menu-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 150px);
  width: 100%;
}

ul.categories {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.category {
  position: relative;
}

/*content*/
.category--content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
          transform: translateX(100%);
}

.category--content h2 {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 44px;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50px);
          transform: translateX(-50px);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.category--content .project-list {
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
}

.category--content,
.category--content .project-list,
.category--content .project-list li {
  text-align: left;
}

.category--name {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: calc(100% - 5px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #666;
  color: #666;
}

.category--name h6 {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: inherit;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.focused .category--name {
  opacity: 0;
}

.projectlist--client {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.projectlist--byline {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Nothing You Could Do', sans-serif;
}

/*last item content*/
.isLast .category--content {
  right: initial;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
          transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.isLast .category--content h2 {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(50px);
          transform: translateX(50px);
  text-align: right;
}

.isLast .category--content .project-list {
  padding: 0 30px 0 0;
}

.isLast .category--content,
.isLast .category--content .project-list,
.isLast .category--content .project-list li {
  text-align: right;
}

/*inactive states*/
li.category {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 500ms ease;
  transition: -webkit-transform 500ms ease;
  transition: transform 500ms ease;
  transition: transform 500ms ease, -webkit-transform 500ms ease;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.category--content {
  text-align: right;
  z-index: -1;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.category--content .project-list li {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.category--image-container {
  background: #222;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}

/*active states*/
li.category.isActive {
  z-index: 99;
}

.isActive .category--content {
  z-index: 99;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.isActive .category--content .project-list li {
  opacity: 1;
}

/*image states*/
.category--image:hover, .category--image:focus, .focused .category--image:hover, .focused .category--image:focus {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.category--image {
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms ease, width 500ms ease 100ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease, width 500ms ease 100ms;
}

.focused .category--image {
  opacity: 0.25;
}

.focused .isActive .category--image {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.category--closeButton {
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: -5rem;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms ease;
  transition: opacity 200ms ease;
}

.focused .isActive .category--closeButton {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 99;
}

.category--closeButton a {
  margin: -15px;
  padding: 15px;
}

/*hover state*/
.category--image {
  /*transition: width 500ms ease;*/
}

.categories--menu-container:not(.focused) li.category:hover .category--name {
  border-color: #eee;
  color: #eee;
}

/*Nav*/
.right-arrow {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.left-arrow {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.left-arrow a, .right-arrow a {
  background-color: #222;
  z-index: 9;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.right-arrow img, .left-arrow img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -45%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -45%);
  z-index: 0;
  width: 140px;
  max-width: none;
}

.left-arrow img {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scaleX(-1);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scaleX(-1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/6.2.0/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/necolas/normalize.css/master/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://codepen.io/nevernotsean/pen/68c150995678a82a39e33f71ef5ce683"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/classnames/2.2.5/index.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/152635/codepen-ga.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: It would be better if you provide the "real React" code (the 3rd textarea in codepen) than the JS above. That's the transpiled code, the output of babel. It's not easy to read.

Comment: @WinChiu opps, so sorry. You're right. I've made the changes to the React code. I think that was the compiled JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The projects inside each categories were set using `setState` inside the `ProjectCategory`. So you need to modify this line:

```
componentWillMount() {
      // this.getProjects(); // Codepen switched to HTTPS, so I have to load JSON manually instead of the json-generator
      this.setState({
        projects: [{"acf":{"project_byline":"ut ullamco sunt","project_credits":[{"credit_role":"ut","credit_name":"Leann"},{"credit_role":"aliquip","credit_name":"Hernandez"},{"credit_role":"consequat","credit_name":"Ashlee"}],"project_description":"Enim est qui Lorem officia adipisicing irure minim. Eu enim fugiat cupidatat elit anim pariatur irure quis aute velit enim. Adipisicing consequat sunt eiusmod reprehenderit nisi fugiat esse ut. Consequat ea ad deserunt mollit quis labore Lorem do qui officia labore. Incididunt reprehenderit anim sunt velit sunt est sit anim.","project_client":"pariatur","project_thumbnail":"https://unsplash.it/1000/1000","project_category":"aute"},"tags":["incididunt"],"categories":[2],"excerpt":{"rendered":"Eiusmod reprehenderit incididunt aute do commodo sint laboris exercitation Lorem excepteur sit cillum aute irure."},"content":{"rendered":"Enim id ex excepteur incididunt in deserunt mollit eiusmod adipisicing officia quis aliquip. Qui aute et consequat consectetur aute consectetur laborum. Non non sint reprehenderit velit proident aliqua elit eiusmod laboris veniam elit ea. Incididunt excepteur et esse minim amet in magna ea enim."},"title":{"rendered":"non"},"link":"https://seanma.de","guid":"7d115e77-9566-4389-b544-deffaf76d058","slug":"proident","id":"58653533ca121cbaf664b199"},{"acf":{"project_byline":"consectetur aute aliquip","project_credits":[{"credit_role":"dolor","credit_name":"Hampton"},{"credit_role":"mollit","credit_name":"Kate"},{"credit_role":"consectetur","credit_name":"Riddle"}],"project_description":"Reprehenderit in mollit fugiat cupidatat consectetur minim Lorem eiusmod commodo laboris dolor minim tempor eiusmod. Et aute et exercitation dolore fugiat pariatur in ipsum anim dolor qui laborum laborum. Elit qui ad ea exercitation laboris sunt ut et est sunt duis. Esse duis ad ipsum aliqua nulla enim minim minim. Ullamco do tempor ex magna et ipsum sint et voluptate cupidatat anim labore esse.","project_client":"et","project_thumbnail":"https://unsplash.it/1000/1001","project_category":"nisi"},"tags":["et"],"categories":[8],"excerpt":{"rendered":"Ipsum excepteur laboris nostrud sit proident."},"content":{"rendered":"Anim non Lorem id fugiat. Do cillum qui veniam qui ad mollit pariatur Lorem. Lorem veniam nulla commodo aliqua. Fugiat laboris cillum excepteur tempor aliqua sit exercitation sit labore nostrud et."},"title":{"rendered":"in"},"link":"http://seanma.de","guid":"444da15a-5160-48bb-bf6f-7d820d1f62e8","slug":"dolor","id":"58653533702dae7921a80c46"},{"acf":{"project_byline":"eiusmod ullamco commodo","project_credits":[{"credit_role":"nulla","credit_name":"Dickson"},{"credit_role":"esse","credit_name":"Trevino"},{"credit_role":"aliquip","credit_name":"Joni"}],"project_description":"Ullamco minim occaecat officia anim laborum laboris velit cupidatat esse aliqua irure exercitation. Occaecat elit labore est exercitation aute qui voluptate adipisicing consectetur officia. Adipisicing tempor tempor culpa enim cupidatat.","project_client":"magna","project_thumbnail":"https://unsplash.it/1000/1002","project_category":"consectetur"},"tags":["incididunt"],"categories":[3],"excerpt":{"rendered":"Tempor quis cupidatat elit quis aute velit amet pariatur cupidatat ullamco voluptate."},"content":{"rendered":"Elit commodo aliqua do occaecat consectetur sint ex. Eiusmod proident eiusmod ullamco occaecat cillum voluptate duis. Tempor enim ullamco duis sint est. Minim voluptate sint nisi enim ut pariatur officia cillum excepteur sint aliquip. Amet in proident dolor amet incididunt laborum sint commodo cillum officia consectetur proident aliqua. Incididunt nostrud nulla mollit adipisicing adipisicing nulla exercitation."},"title":{"rendered":"tempor"},"link":"http://seanma.de","guid":"75909710-4410-4b59-bec8-f5cbb342471a","slug":"ullamco","id":"58653533e961f59631955144"},{"acf":{"project_byline":"culpa tempor commodo","project_credits":[{"credit_role":"eiusmod","credit_name":"Pennington"},{"credit_role":"fugiat","credit_name":"Jocelyn"},{"credit_role":"enim","credit_name":"Byrd"}],"project_description":"Cupidatat incididunt laborum cillum ea dolore quis. Exercitation Lorem eu ad ex. Laboris ipsum excepteur sunt eu irure ipsum. Consequat cupidatat sunt Lorem proident nostrud velit voluptate nulla quis cillum fugiat. Mollit fugiat nulla enim irure commodo officia nulla minim incididunt labore. Labore cillum irure Lorem ut laborum ad laborum.","project_client":"sint","project_thumbnail":"https://unsplash.it/1000/1003","project_category":"do"},"tags":["adipisicing"],"categories":[7],"excerpt":{"rendered":"Nostrud laborum aliquip enim aute aute tempor."},"content":{"rendered":"Consectetur fugiat commodo aliquip culpa occaecat anim cupidatat adipisicing cupidatat voluptate reprehenderit incididunt. Irure consequat enim deserunt incididunt dolor nisi id do cupidatat in Lorem. Laborum amet id minim enim. Nulla sint enim commodo ut qui duis reprehenderit Lorem nulla. Ad sint aliquip aute Lorem ut reprehenderit duis dolore occaecat non. Elit deserunt amet laborum non labore est deserunt eiusmod."},"title":{"rendered":"nulla"},"link":"http://seanma.de","guid":"9581e2ce-8146-4cf5-8d0b-9107ab850828","slug":"non","id":"58653533c66184064ccedc40"},{"acf":{"project_byline":"ex deserunt est","project_credits":[{"credit_role":"non","credit_name":"Hutchinson"},{"credit_role":"quis","credit_name":"Donaldson"},{"credit_role":"aliqua","credit_name":"Marcie"}],"project_description":"Eu ullamco anim adipisicing duis adipisicing sint sit incididunt pariatur sit. Non veniam deserunt nulla aute. Eiusmod minim ut Lorem consequat. Ut ad ad qui do aute. Duis ipsum do consequat exercitation nisi anim id laboris fugiat dolore ex ut consectetur excepteur. Esse deserunt nostrud esse consectetur pariatur mollit. Enim proident enim non occaecat eu sint nostrud.","project_client":"occaecat","project_thumbnail":"https://unsplash.it/1000/1004","project_category":"sit"},"tags":["aliqua"],"categories":[3],"excerpt":{"rendered":"Esse commodo amet excepteur ex ad."},"content":{"rendered":"Commodo ad et veniam sunt non pariatur elit ex anim esse consequat veniam. Ad magna nulla ea anim est in nostrud magna magna proident voluptate officia. Irure nisi do adipisicing nostrud mollit est non duis quis nisi amet veniam Lorem proident."},"title":{"rendered":"mollit"},"link":"http://seanma.de","guid":"472ababf-2340-4301-b63d-9bec9640a19e","slug":"incididunt","id":"586535332e3781792a099619"}]
      })
    }
```

1. Just modify the value inside the brackets `[]`, by creating 2
   dimensional array. The above only one dimensional.
2. Modify this line to:

   ```
   class ProjectList extends React.Component {
   render() {
       let idx = this.props.idx;
       let el = this.props.projects[idx];
       return (
           <div className="project-list">
               <ul className="menu vertical">
                 { el.map( this.createProjectListItem ) }
               </ul>
           </div>
       )
   }
   ```

   }
3. Modify this line (inside the `class ProjectCategory` to:

   ```
       <ProjectList projects={this.state.projects} idx={this.props.Index} />
   ```

Comment: I tried that. The thing is it changes all 5 of the "categories" "projects". Am I able to have the 'projects: [];' stuff 5 different times and have it output each one for each section. Hope this is making sense. Thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: My mistake. Just edited my answer. You need to create two dimensional array first (each contains 5 elements). Something like: `[[{"acf":{"project_byline"...,"id":"586535332e3781792a099619"}],[{"acf":{"project_byline"...,"id":"586535332e3781792a099619"}],[{"acf":{"project_byline"...,"id":"586535332e3781792a099619"}],[{"acf":{"project_byline"...,"id":"586535332e3781792a099619"}],[{"acf":{"project_byline"...,"id":"586535332e3781792a099619"}]]`

Comment: I tried this out and it kept messing up. Frustrating, but I'll keep looking at it. If you're able to fork that Codepen project and are able to get it to work, I'd love to check over what you did differently to get it to work. I greatly appreciate your help so far!

Comment: oh wow thank you! It worked great. Almost perfect. One last issue I'm coming across. On the line `<div className={'categories--menu-container ' + classes} onClick={this._focusOff} style={{height: window.innerHeight}}>` I took out the "onClick" so when clicking on the project it would open a link instead of closing the category. That worked but when doing so it takes the 'Back' button's clickability away. I've tried to add the 'onClick' to just the 'Back' button with no success. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean the browser's back button? Weird, because that code does not use react-router at all. Please share your edited code (just the edited section).

Comment: not the browsers back button. In the Codepen post you made for me, when you click a category it shows the projects and at the bottom shows the text 'back' that will collapse the category and show the default view. Currently, if you click a project it just collapses the category, that's not really what should happen. The 'back' button should collapse the category and the projects should be linkable to anywhere. (part two below)

Comment: So,I took this `<a to={'/projects/' + project.slug}>` to this `<a href={project.link}>' --- then I took `        <div className={'categories--menu-container ' + classes} onClick={this._focusOff} style={{height: window.innerHeight}}>` to this `<div className={'categories--menu-container ' + classes} style={{height: window.innerHeight}}>` (removing the onClick) --- and then finally tried adding the onClick to here `<a href="#" onClick={this._focusOff}>Back</a>'. This is what I assumed would work, but that's not the case.

Comment: That won't work, since the `_focusOff` function is not in the same class. I believe your console showed error. Try this instead: `<a href="#" onClick={this.props.focusOff}>Back</a>`

Comment: That worked perfectly, the whole thing is working great! Thank you so much, I apprecaite it.

Comment: No problem. If I suggest, pls read the react docs. Especially [this section](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html). Because you seem confused how the props work.

Answer (score 1):

JSX *(JavaScript XML)* cannot be run in your browser directly. You need to trans-pile your JSX file into pure JavaScript in order to run this in your browser. Use [BabelJS](https://babeljs.io/) for this.

Comment: I know this. That wasn't what my issue was. It was not undestanding how the connection between multiple arrays. @winchiu helped with that already. Thank you.